# How do I select a series in a spline by clicking on the spline in between the points?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to be able to select a series in my spline chart by clicking on the line in between two points. The problem is, every x co-ordinate is within a category as there is no space "between categories", so when I move the mouse cursor between two points it will highlight either one or the other point, depending on which is closer. I have snap set very low.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [custom-events](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events) plugin, which allows to catch click event on series line.